# Read single-value output that is written to EXCEL

Tags: sql, excel, powershell

My powershell script runs an SQL query and outputs it to EXCEL

```
$SQL2 = "SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT EVENT_DESC) AS Number_of_Downloads,
    COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.V_SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_NAME) AS Number_of_Computers
FROM
    dbo.V_AGENT_SYSTEM_LOG,  dbo.V_SEM_COMPUTER

$ws = $wb.Worksheets.Item(2)
$ws.name = "Totals"


$qt = $ws.QueryTables.Add("ODBC;DSN=$DSN;UID=$username;PWD=$password", $ws.Range("A1"), $SQL2)

if ($qt.Refresh()){
    $ws.Activate()
    $ws.Select()
    $excel.Rows.Item(1).HorizontalAlignment = $xlCenter
    $excel.Rows.Item(1).VerticalAlignment = $xlTop
    $excel.Rows.Item("1:1").Font.Name = "Calibri" 
    $excel.Rows.Item("1:1").Font.Size = 11 
    $excel.Rows.Item("1:1").Font.Bold = $true 
 }
```

The EXCEL output is

[image]

How do I read the value of 2484 into powershell variable?

Right now, I query the database twice, and the value of "Number_of_Computers" changes in a matter of seconds, hence I need to record the value only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the .Value2 property of the cell in question. This should do it for you:

```
$NumOfComps = $ws.Cells.item(2).value2
```

Sorry, you can get an exact cell with:

```
$NumOfComps = $ws.Range("B2","B2")
```

That just specifies a single cell range.

Comment: When I try this I get "Number_of_Computers" instead of the cell below it, i.e. 2484 ..... I'm trying to research how to pinpoint the exact cell location. I've tried $NumOfComps = $ws.Cells.item(2).value2, $NumOfComps = $ws.Cells.item(2).value3, $NumOfComps = $ws.Cells.item(1).value2 ....

Comment: You can always pinpoint a cell by selecting it as a Range() object via the WorkSheet's method. Answer updated.

Comment: Now I get System._ComObject

Comment: I also tried $NumOfComps = $ws.Range("B2","B2").value but I get Variant Value (Variant) {get} {set}

Comment: This is what worked, $NumOfComps = $ws.Range("B2","B2").value2

Answer (score 1):

How about using range A1:B1

```
$Range = $ws.QueryTables.Add("ODBC;DSN=$DSN;UID=$username;PWD=$password", $ws.Range("A1:B1"), $SQL2)
```

Comment: when I try this I get the value "System.__ComObject"